# SQL query to select from two nested sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a pretty hard sql query on my HW assignment and i am kind of stuck. any hints would be appreciated.

my query:

```
SELECT nest1.carname, 
       nest1.plndescription, 
       nest1.plancount, 
       nest2.totalmems, 
       Round(( nest1.plancount / nest2.totalmems ), 2) AS pct 
FROM   (SELECT carriers.carname, 
               p.plndescription, 
               Count(members.planid)AS plancount 
        FROM   carriers, 
               plans p, 
               members 
        WHERE  carriers.carrierid = p.carrierid 
               AND p.planid = members.planid 
        GROUP  BY carriers.carname, 
                  p.plndescription)nest1 
       NATURAL JOIN (SELECT carriers.carrierid, 
                            Count(members.planid)AS totalmems 
                     FROM   carriers, 
                            plans p, 
                            members 
                     WHERE  carriers.carrierid = p.carrierid 
                            AND p.planid = members.planid 
                     GROUP  BY carriers.carrierid)nest2 
ORDER  BY nest1.carname
```

my tables and relationships;

```
` CREATE TABLE Carriers
( CarrierID varchar2(4) not null,
  carName varchar2(35),
  carAddress varchar2(50),
  carCity varchar2(30),
  carStCode varchar2(2),
  carZip varchar2(10),
  carPhone varchar2(10),
  carWebSite varchar2(255),
  carContactFirstname varchar2(35),
  carContactLastName varchar2(35),
  carContactEmail varchar2(255),

 CONSTRAINT pk_CarrierID PRIMARY KEY (CarrierID)
 );`

 CREATE TABLE Plans
 ( PlanID integer not null,
  plnDescription varchar2(35),
  plnCost decimal (8,2),
  CarrierID varchar2(4),

CONSTRAINT pk_PlanID PRIMARY KEY (PlanID),
CONSTRAINT fk_CarrierID FOREIGN KEY (CarrierId) REFERENCES Carriers
);

   CREATE TABLE Members
( MemberNo integer not null,
  mbrFirstname varchar2(35),
  mbrLastName varchar2(35),
  mbrStreet varchar2(50),
  mbrCity varchar2(30),
  mbrState varchar2(2),
  mbrZip varchar2(10),
  mbrPhoneNo varchar2(10),
  PlanID integer,
  mbrEmail varchar2(255),
  mbrDateEffective date,
  employerID integer,

    CONSTRAINT pk_MemberNo PRIMARY KEY (MemberNo),
    CONSTRAINT fk_PlanID FOREIGN KEY (PlanId) REFERENCES Plans,
    CONSTRAINT fk_employerID FOREIGN KEY (employerID) REFERENCES employers
    );
```

the problem :
Create a query that will list all Carriers and their Plans along with a column that displays the number of members in that Plan, the total number of members serviced by the Carrier and the percent of the Carrier’s Members that are in that Plan.  For Example – Blue Cross Blue Shield – would display as follows:

correct output:

```
Carrier                 Plan                    PlanCount  TotalMems  Pct
Blue Cross Blue Shield  2-Party Basic Medical   10         22         45.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy, I wouldn't want to type that much.  I didn't check to see if these parse correctly, but since it is homework it should be too easy.

if you were using mysql I would do it like this and use session variables with subqueries:

```
select c.carName As Carrier
     , p.plnDescription As Plan
     , count(1) As PlanCount
     , (select @plnCount:=count(1) from members m where m.PlanId=p.PlanId) TotalMems
     , (select @plnCount/count(1) from members) Pct
 from carriers c
 left join plans p on p.CarrierId=c.CarrierId
```

but your ddl indicates you are using oracle (b/c varchar2), so something more like:

```
select c.carName As Carrier
     , p.plnDescription As Plan
     , PlanCount
     , PlanCount/tot Pct
 from carriers c
     ,plans p on p.CarrierId=c.CarrierId
     ,(select sum(decode(m.planId,p.planId,1,0)) PlanCount, count(1) tot from members)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do with the following.  The lowest query is just a query of ALL MEMBERS regardless of which plan a person is in.  This will need to be run on its own in the query execution plan as it will result in a single record and applied to every record for the rest of the query.  This results with no actual JOIN or WHERE clause.

Next, the first part of the from does a pre-aggregation on just the plan ID and count of members per specific plan grouped by plan.

Now, get into proper JOIN clause to pull in the details of the plan for it's description, then the carrier for the carrier name, then order it by whatever you want...

```
SELECT
      C.CarName,
      P.PlnDescription,
      PerPlan.PerPlanCount,
      ( PerPlan.PerPlanCount / AllPlans.AllMembers ) as PcntOfAllMembers
   from
      ( select M.PlanID, COUNT(*) as PerPlanCount
           from Members M
           group by M.PlanID ) PerPlan
           Join Plans P
              ON PerPlan.PlanID = P.PlanID
              Join Carriers C
                 ON P.CarrierID = C.CarrierID,
      ( select COUNT(*) AllMembersCount
           from Members ) AllPlans 
   order by
      C.CarName,
      P.PlnDescription
```

You had a count of 10 for a plan count on your sample, but nothing to indicate multiple sub-plans for '2-Party Basic Medical', so I don't think that is a real column per the data.

HOWEVER, if the 10 is a representation of how many distinct plans that 'Blue Cross' has, and that '2-Party...' is one of those plans, that would be a different query.